# Проблема с русскими символами

Tags: c, символы

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *msg = "Не звони мне";
    puts(msg+3);
    return 0;
}
```

По идее, вывод должен быть "звони мне", но выводится "� звони мне". Единственное логичное объяснение, которое я нашёл, это то, что русские символы занимают 2 байта, и потому "Не" и пробел будет 5 байтов `puts(msg+5);`. Разве этим не должен заниматься компилятор?

Comment: Этим занимается ваш текстовый редактор, который позволяет вам сохранить файл в любой доступной кодировке. Видимо, вы сохранили файл в UTF-8, вот в массиве байтов `msg` и оказалась закодированная в UTF-8 строка

Comment: @AlexGlebe, wchar_t не является серебряной пулей и не покрывает современные реалии, он по-моему даже как obsolete помечен. А, он ещё и не переносим между системами (есть 16-битовый и 32-битовый варианты). Так что лучше посимвольно обрабатывать...

Answer (score 1):

В Си массивы имеют только фиксированные размеры элементов. В строках или по байту или по два байта. А UTF-8 имеет плавающий размер (1-6) байт. Если вам нужны точная фиксация элементов строки , то придётся пользоваться wchar_t со всеми вытекающими функциями конвертации.

```
// gcc -Wall -std=c11 -Wextra dontring.c -o dontring
# include <stdio.h>
# include <wchar.h>
# include <locale.h>
int main()
{
  setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    wchar_t const msg[] = L"Не звони мне";
    fputws(&(msg[3]),stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

вывод :

```
> ./dontring 
звони мне
```

Comment: wchar_t не является серебряной пулей и не покрывает современные реалии, он по-моему даже как obsolete помечен. А, он ещё и не переносим между системами (есть 16-битовый и 32-битовый варианты). Так что лучше посимвольно обрабатывать...

Comment: В Си ваше obsolete будет игнорироваться ещё 50 лет. Кому надо будет юзать. Я 16-битный проц не видел давно. 8086 чоли? Как вам удобно обрабатывать по-пол символа скажите мне? @0andriy

Comment: Не в процессоре дело, вы между строк читаете? Я про железо слова не сказал.

Comment: Ну когда отменят байт как obsolete и все тексты будут с 16-битной кодировкой тогда и поговорим. @0andriy

Comment: Вы вообще поняли о чём я? Вместо надменного тона почитали бы что ли вот эту дискуссию к примеру: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548465/is-16-bit-wchar-t-formally-valid-for-representing-full-unicode а то понапишете всякого, а вам поверят.